# Eclipse don't create automatically .xml file and .java file when I create new android project

Tags: android

Eclipse don't create automatically .xml file and .java file when I create new android project.I looked same problems solves before but I couldn't solve this.I think I had this problem because of appcompat_v7 or support library.Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: when you created the project did you select `Create Activity`

Comment: I tried but not working also this way

Comment: well if you can't create an Activity then you wont get the `activity.java` or the `layout.xml` that the activity is composed of.

Comment: I know i tried both of them.Program created before but when i uptade something don't crete anymore.

Comment: in project explorer `right click -> new -> Android activity` or `right click -> new ->other -> Android activity`

Comment: Not working also this way.I can just create seperately xml and activity.java file.

Comment: well I dont have much to go on any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It is a but in the latest version of eclipse ADB plugin. Upgrades must be released soon.
A Quick fix for now is to create a "**Empty Activity**" instead of "Blank activity".

```
new -> Android activity -> choose "Empty Activity"
```